# How can I format the output of "grep"?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have this `grep` command:

```
grep -e PIPPO -e PLUTO -e TOPOLINO *.csv >> result.txt
```

I want the output to have this format:

```
path of file, row of file, text found
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting grep options in http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
grep -Hn -e PIPPO -e PLUTO -e TOPOLINO *.csv >> result.txt
```

You can run the grep in a different directory if you want the full path:

```
cd /
grep -Hn -e PIPPO -e PLUTO -e TOPOLINO /your/path/*.csv >> result.txt
```

If you want to only show the matching parts add the `-o` parameter to grep:

```
grep -Hno -e PIPPO -e PLUTO -e TOPOLINO *.csv >> result.txt
```

Comment: In fact `-H` is not necessary as it is default when you are grepping more than one file at the time. I guess.

Comment: If `*.csv` happens to be only one file it's needed. I like being explicit.

Comment: Yes, sure, I also think it is better to add it just in case.

Comment: But only row printed don't cointein only the word found.
Print all row that cointein the word selected